# Programmatically call authorize - spring security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm using spring security 5.1.6 to expose an oauth2 server and I would like to call "oauth/authorize" programmatically from server. Is there any method to call it directly? I don't want to call it through a rest call.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. What is the role of your server? Example: Authorization Server or Resource Server or Client Server...
 
What endpoints are there?

Give your security configuration.

Comment: It's Authorization Server